# Pandas Groupby to_csv not able to add header

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to do groupby on a dataset in pandas and write it out to csv. While I am able to do it, I am not able to add a header as _reset_index() is failing. I have the code below (with the reset_index line commented out).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Ticker':['enb','cn.enb','enb','aapl','nan','box','ENB.PF.I','ENB.PR.U','TENB','LENB','T','T'],
'Id':['2n3','2n3','2n3','alpha','NA','','2n3','8w2','r43','x45','u1','c1'],
'Values':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
})
print(df)
a = df.groupby('Ticker')['Ticker'].count().sort_values(ascending=False)
# b=a.reset_index()
a.to_csv('b.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to have something like

```
a.to_csv('b.csv', header=['Count'])
```

This works because it is a series. not a dataframe